# Delphi-FastReport VCL 5 Conditional highlighting

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, fastreport

I've read [this manual](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/html/FR5UserManual-HTML-en/index.html?conditional_highlighting.htm) , and follow it , but the `highlighting` not working.

**What I have?**

- Create new VCL application.
- Drop a `TEdit` and `TButton` components in the form (To pass the value).
- Drop a `TfrxReport` on the form.
- Open the report in design mode.
- Drop a `ReportTile` band in the report page.
- Drop a `TfrxMemoView` in the ReportTitle band.
- Add conditions:

  ```
   1- Value <= 0 -> Red color
   2- Value > 0 -> Green color
  ```

The fill color of the memo still `Black` even the value is `>0` or `<=0`.

**The question:**

Why this conditions not working? and how can I make the conditions work?

[image]

**Update:**

The value was passed to the `TfrxMemoView` component as :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var Mem : TfrxMemoView;
begin
Mem := frxReport1.FindObject('Memo1') as TfrxMemoView;
Mem.Text := Edit1.Text;
frxReport1.ShowReport();
end;
```

Comment: Does your `TfrxMemoView` object have numeric `Value`? It seems to be empty on your screenshot.

Comment: @Victoria I send the value from a `TEdit` component to the `TfrxMemoView` component , Will update the question.

Comment: Don't have FastReport by hand, but shouldn't that be `Value` property that should be set (not `Text`)? And if so, it should be variant data type that may expect integer data type for that expression rather than text, so maybe you'd need to write `Mem.Value := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);`.

Comment: @Victoria That what I find in the manual as you see.

Comment: I can see no Delphi code example there. Only expression examples for those highlighter conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the rules is applied because the **Value** property remains **NULL**. To assign a constant value from Delphi code you can either write a constant expression, for example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Memo: TfrxMemoView;
begin
  Memo := frxReport1.FindObject('Memo1') as TfrxMemoView;
  Memo.Text := Format('[%s]', [Edit1.Text]);
  frxReport1.ShowReport;
end;
```

In the above code I've omitted check if the control was found. And, you need to be careful with the input text. It accepts only floating point values in format that won't collide in decimal separator with separator(s) defined in the **ExpressionDelimiters** property.

Or simply set the **Value** property as well:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Memo: TfrxMemoView;
begin
  Memo := frxReport1.FindObject('Memo1') as TfrxMemoView;
  Memo.Text := Edit1.Text;
  Memo.Value := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  frxReport1.ShowReport;
end;
```

In this one the check if the control was found is missing as well. And the conversion to float is not necessary there. The **Value** can be just a string convertible to float.

Comment: Or use `Memo.Text := '[' + StrToInt(Edit1.Text) + ']';`

Comment: @gpi Really? assign `Integer` to a `WideString`? No way. mybe you mean `Memo.Text := '[' + Edit1.Text + ']';` and that is true.

Comment: Yes, I mean `Memo.Text := '[' + Edit1.Text + ']'`

Comment: @gpi, yes, writing expression is not a bad idea actually. You just need to be careful with the decimal vs. expression separator. Updated.